# Should I store failed login attempts in AWS Cognito or Dynamo DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a requirement to build a basic "3 failed login attempts and your account gets locked" functionality. The project uses AWS Cognito for Authentication, and the Cognito PreAuth and PostAuth triggers to run a Lambda function look like they will help here.

So the basic flow is to increment a counter in the PreAuth lambda, check it and block login there, or reset the counter in the PostAuth lambda (so successful logins dont end up locking the user out). Essentially it boils down to:

**PreAuth Lambda**

```
if failed-login-count > LIMIT:
    block login
else:
    increment failed-login-count
```

**PostAuth Lambda**

```
reset failed-login-count to zero
```

Now at the moment I am using a dedicated DynamoDB table to store the failed-login-count for a given user. This seems to work fine for now.
Then I figured it'd be neater to use a custom attribute in Cognito (using `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminUpdateUserAttributes`) so I could throw away the DynamoDB table.

However reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-dg.pdf the section titled "Configuring User Pool Attributes" states:

> Attributes are pieces of information that help you identify individual users, such as name, email, and phone number. Not all information about your users should be stored in attributes. For example, user data that changes frequently, such as usage statistics or game scores, should be kept in a separate data store, such as Amazon Cognito Sync or Amazon DynamoDB.

Given that the counter will change on every single login attempt, the docs would seem to indicate I shouldn't do this...

But can anyone tell me why? Or if there would be some negative consequence of doing so?
As far as I can see, Cognito billing is purely based on storage (i.e. number of users), and not operations, whereas Dynamo charges for read/write/storage.
Could it simply be AWS not wanting people to abuse Cognito as a storage mechanism? Or am I being daft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are dealing with similar problem and main reason why we have decided to store extra attributes in DB is that Cognito has quotas for all the actions and "AdminUpdateUserAttributes" is limited to 25 per second.

More information here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html

So if you have a pool with 100k or more it can create a bottle neck if wanted to update a Cognito user records with every login etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cognito UserAttributes are meant to store information about the users. This information can then be read from the client using the AWS Cognito SDK, or just by decoding the `idToken` on the client-side. Every custom attribute you add will be visible on the client-side.

Another downside of custom attributes is that:

- You only have 25 values to set
- They cannot be removed or changed once added to the user pool.

I have personally used custom attributes and the interface to manipulate them is not excellent. But that is just a personal thought.

If you want to store this information, and not depend on DynamoDB, you can use Amazon Cognito Sync. Besides the service, it offers a client with great features that you can incorporate to your app.

Comment: It's not true that every custom attribute will be visible on the client side. There is a read/write permission in the cognito configuration that you can turn on/off for attributes. If 'read' is off, the client will never be able to see that particular attribute. I considered Cognito Sync, but this seems geared for syncing data on a device, which is not appropriate to this use case. 25 max attributes and being unable to remove them is a valid point though, thanks.

Comment: For your usecase, DynamoDB seems like the best alternative.

Answer (score 1):

AWS DynamoDb appears to be your best option, it is commonly used for such use cases. Some of the benefits of using it:

- You can store separate record for each login attempt with as much info as you want such as ip address, location, user-agent etc. You can also add datetime that can be used by pre-auth Lambda to query by time range for example failed attempt within last 30 minutes
- You don't need to manage table because you can set [TTL for DynamoDb record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html) so that record will be deleted automatically after specified time.
- You can also [archive items in S3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/automatically-archive-items-to-s3-using-dynamodb-time-to-live-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-kinesis-firehose/)